# setgid bit not preserved by git on new directory in `.git` folder?

Tags: linux, git, bash, filesystems, file-permissions

I have a bare git repository setup for user `fred`:

```
/home/fred/foo.git
```

I have set the group of every file in `foo.git` to `bar`:

```
$ chown -R fred:bar /home/fred/foo.git
```

(Note that `fred` is not a member of group `bar`)

And I have set the `setgid` bit on for every directory in `foo.git`:

```
$ find foo.git -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s
```

However when `fred` commits to the git repository, the group is not preserved in some files.

Specifically in the `objects` directory I see:

```
foo.git/objects:
drwxrws--- 46 fred bar 4096 Apr  7 23:43 .
drwxrws---  7 fred bar 4096 Apr  6 17:12 ..
drwxrws---  2 fred bar 4096 Apr  6 17:11 07
drwxrws---  2 fred bar 4096 Apr  6 17:11 10
drwxrwx---  2 fred bar 4096 Apr  7 22:14 14  <--- HERE
drwxrws---  2 fred bar 4096 Apr  6 17:11 17

      ^--- HERE
```

Notice that in `objects/14` the `setgid` bit is not set.  So consequently when a new object is added to that directory:

```
foo.git/objects/14:
drwxrwx---  2 fred bar 4096 Apr  7 22:14 .
drwxrws--- 46 fred bar 4096 Apr  7 23:43 ..
-r--r-----  1 fred fred    2595 Apr  7 22:14 95482f8..9d6bfe21
```

So now the `95482..` file doesn't have group `bar`, it has group `fred`.

I suspect that when `fred` commited, git created a new directory on-demand called `objects/14` to hold a new object, when it did this for some unknown reason the `setgid` bit on the new `14` directory was not set, even though its parent directory `objects` has the `setgid` bit set.

If I try to reproduce this manually:

```
$ su fred                          # as user fred
$ mkdir test1                      # create test1 dir
$ sudo chgrp bar test1             # set group to bar
$ sudo chmod g+s test1             # set setgid bit
$ ls -l
drwxrwsr-x 2 fred bar 4096 Apr  8 21:33 test1

$ mkdir test1/test2                # create dir test1/test2
$ ls -l
drwxrwsr-x 2 fred bar 4096 Apr  8 21:35 test2

      ^--- HERE
```

Notice the `setgid` bit in the new `test1/test2` **is** preserved, so when I...

```
$ touch test1/test2/test3
```

The new file is still group `bar` as expected:

```
$ ls -l test1/test2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fred bar 0 Apr  8 21:36 test3
```

Why doesn't `git` seem to preserve the `setgid` bit when it creates new directories in the `.git` directory?

Is there some git setting I can make to fix this?  Or can you explain what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when you specify the `core.sharedrepository` config, git does `chmod()`s on the files it creates.  That way, the result is correct despite filesystem types and mount options, *except* in your one case where the repository owner isn't a member of the group it's shared with.

That bad result happens because git's `chmod()` appears to succeed -- you can see it in an strace -- but ignores anything the issuing user isn't authorized to ask for.

So to avoid that weirdity, the thing to do is

```
git config --unset core.sharedrepository
```

(or not specify --shared at all on the init) so git doesn't touch the filesystem's default permissions at all.  Amusingly enough that makes everything work:

```
~/sandbox/75276/s$ find ../s.git -ls
12193569    4 drwxrws---   4 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:52 ../s.git
12193571    4 -rw-rw----   1 jthill   mail           73 Apr  8 20:40 ../s.git/description
12193572    4 -rw-rw----   1 jthill   mail           23 Apr  8 20:40 ../s.git/HEAD
12721086    4 drwxrws---   2 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:52 ../s.git/objects
12193570    4 drwxrws---   2 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:52 ../s.git/refs
12193578    4 -rw-rw----   1 jthill   mail          104 Apr  9 13:37 ../s.git/config
~/sandbox/75276/s$ cat ../s.git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
[receive]
        denyNonFastforwards = true
~/sandbox/75276/s$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 198 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /home/jthill/sandbox/75276/s.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
~/sandbox/75276/s$ find ../s.git -ls
12193569    4 drwxrws---   4 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:52 ../s.git
12193571    4 -rw-rw----   1 jthill   mail           73 Apr  8 20:40 ../s.git/description
12193572    4 -rw-rw----   1 jthill   mail           23 Apr  8 20:40 ../s.git/HEAD
12721086    4 drwxrws---   5 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/objects
16777964    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/objects/58
16777965    4 -r--r--r--   1 jthill   mail           17 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/objects/58/7be6b4c3f93f93c489c0111bba5596147a26cb
16777962    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/objects/ab
16777963    4 -r--r--r--   1 jthill   mail           46 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/objects/ab/69b4abf3bb84d4e268bd42d84e4a9a5e242bd3
16777960    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/objects/81
16777961    4 -r--r--r--   1 jthill   mail          120 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/objects/81/210f2df9629e5df5f6dfa0923a2cf72369314d
12193570    4 drwxrws---   3 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/refs
12193573    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 jthill   mail         4096 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/refs/heads
12193574    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 jthill   mail           41 Apr  9 13:53 ../s.git/refs/heads/master
12193578    4 -rw-rw----   1 jthill   mail          104 Apr  9 13:37 ../s.git/config
~/sandbox/75276/s$
```

Comment: I already have `core.sharedRepository = 0660` set.  I can't change it because I don't want the repository to be world readable.  With `core.sharedRepositoy = 0660` the described behaviour (not preserving setgid bit) is observed.

Comment: Won't this (undesirably) set the `setgid` bit for files as well as directories?

Comment: how long after somebody implemented it that way do you think it would take for the derisive howls of laughter to start?  no, git's "the stupid content tracker" and all, but I really think he's using that word to mean something else in this context.

Comment: Neither `02660` nor `2660` work.  The sharedRepository config variable must be in the form `0xxx`.

Comment: The sharedrepository line has not effect in this case.  If you repeat your example with the `git config` line omitted it still works.  To reproduce the problem you need to create a bare repository, and then push to it. [Demonstration here](http://pastebin.com/xWeSRzU8)

Comment: I just went hunting, [it works as far back as git v1.7.1](http://pastebin.com/dtqKW6qy), coming up three years old now, what version of git do you have?

Comment: I have `1.7.10.4`.  Is `jthill` a member of the group `adm` ?  Try using a group that `jthill` is not a member of ?

Comment: So, my apologies for being so dense about the owning-user-not-in-the-repo's-group bit, it just didn't make enough sense to me to sink in, I hope you'll be as amused as I am at what the answer turned out to be.