# Git on Windows - How to authenticate with remote repo on Linux

Tags: windows, git, ssh

Due to some serious problems with a Git repo on Windows over HTTP, we're moving our Git 'server' to Linux.

Assuming I have already the msysgit for Windows installed and Putty, how will I authenticate the SSH connection when I clone, pull and push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of SSH:

- on the server, you'll need to allow authentication with public and private keys, you can google how to do it, for example http://shapeshed.com/setting_up_git_for_multiple_developers/
- on the client, just put your private key into `.ssh` folder in your windows home, for example `C:\Users\Name\.ssh`, much like on unixes.

You can still use HTTP, it will either (1) always ask for username and password or (2) you can also put username and password into the URL: `https://username:password@git.mydomain.com/...`

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/68161-how-to-install-git-in-windows-using-putty) has everything covered about using PuTTy for Git public key authentication. 
In short:

- Generate keypair with puttygen
- Put the public key in server
- In your local computer, set GIT_SSH environment variable to point to plink.exe
- Run putty pageant and load your private key there

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working through [this tutorial](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/index.html).

The caveat is that it talks about github, so the story of telling the server about your SSH key is different.

What's also different is how do you intend to manage your developers.
The "problem" is that SSH operates with real remote (server-side, I mean) users, which have to have regular Unix system accounts.

This is okay if you have just a handful of developers. You then just need to add all of them to a special group (say, `devel`) and make sure you initialize your server-side bare repos using `git init --bare --shared=group` and make them group-writable and belonging to that group `devel` (this might also be helped out by creating all the repos under a directory which has its ["group sticky bit" set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832402/720999) and belongs to that group `devel`).

To distribute the public part of a developer's key to the server in such a setup you have to literally copy and paste that key part (from the developer's `id_rsa.pub` file, it's ASCII) to the file `/home/developer/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. If that file does not exist, create it.
If the key was generated on a machine with OpenSSH client installed, you can transfer the key using the `ssh-copy-id` program, in one step.

This might become messy, so you might consider implementing a solution which virtualizes Git users (like github does). There are plenty to choose from:

- [`gitolite`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) — supposedly the most popular solution. No frills, is administered using a specialized admin Git repo holding the developers' public keys and a configuration file describing the repos and permissions on them. Plain Perl, installable as a package on most sensible distros.
- [`gitlab`](http://gitlab.org/) — a turn-key all-in-one solution. Written in Ruby, so you might face maintenance nightmares.
- [`gitblit`](http://gitblit.com/) — another all-in-one solution, written in pure Java (note that it does not call out to vanilla Git and uses a pure Java Git layer — JGit).